# How to insert a JQuery icon button inside a page? (Some doubts)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am pretty new in **Jquery** and I have the following doubt related about how to insert an **icon button** inside a page.

I found this example: http://jqueryui.com/button/#icons

So I think that if I want to insert an **icon button** I have to do something like this:

```
<button>Button with icon only</button>
```

and into the **...** section I have to put something like it:

```
$(function() {
    $( "button:first" ).button({
      icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-locked"
      },
      text: false
    })
});
```

Is it correct?

From what can I understand it seems to me that this "script" is used to set the icon to my button.

What exactly do this line:

```
$( "button:first" ).button(
```

I think that it is used to associate the previous script to the proper  tag in my HTML code. In this case the **first button in the HTML**. Is it right or am I missing something?

It it is correct, can I associate the script using an html id or class?

for example if I have something like this

```
<button id="myButton">Button with icon only</button>
```

can I associate the script to the button having **myButton** as **ID**?

Tnx

Comment: $( "#myButton" ).button(....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used sometext you have typed .

> 1) "So I think that if I want to insert an icon button I have to do
>   something like this:

```
> <button>Button with icon only</button>
```

> and into the ... section I have
>
> > to put something like it:
>
> $(function() {
>       $( "button:first" ).button({
>         icons: {
>           primary: "ui-icon-locked"
>         },
>         text: false
>       }) });"

**Yes , if you want to insert a Iconbutton ,you need insert the button tag.**

> 2)$( "button:first" ).button(

This exactly means what you have asked.It is pointing to the first button in the script.just works like the selector in the css

> 3)can I associate the script to the button having myButton as ID?

yes, you can do it.after all jquery needs a selector an ID so as a CSS class will definitely work that way.

just to keep it simple i have linked a fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/LLBQu/8/

*Note:I haven't created that fiddle i have just customized as per your questions.*

Comment: Tnx, your explaination it is very helpfull for me :-)